# Finding distribution of product of jointly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are random variables jointly uniformly distributed over the square with corners $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1)$ and $(0,1)$. I need to find the CDF and PDF of $X$ defined by $X=UV$. 
$$\mathbb{P}(UV\leq x) = \begin{cases}0 \text{ if x > 1 or x< 0}\\
x \text{ if 0}\leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}$$

For the PDF, I'd replace $x$ with $1$.
Can someone please verify if the CDF and PDF are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\geq1$ then $P(UV\leq x)=1$ (not $0$).

If $0<x<1$ then:

$$P\left(UV\leq x\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathsf{1}_{\left(-\infty,x\right]}\left(uv\right)dudv=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\min\left(1,\frac{x}{v}\right)}dudv=\int_{0}^{1}\min\left(1,\frac{x}{v}\right)dv=\cdots$$

I leave the rest to you (split up in $0<v\leq x$ and $x<v<1$).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the first error, that was silly on my part

Comment: To complete, the CDF, $\int_{0}^{x}1dv + \int_{x}^{1}\frac{x}{v}dv=x+xln(v)|_{x}^{1} = x-xln(x)$. And the PDF $-ln(x)$ for $0<x<1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.